# Reading a csv file into a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have read answers similar to this questions, but do not find such as solution to my goal. I have a large `csv` file of nearly 150MB, having the following form:

```
logs.csv:

id,lat,lon,days,mode
656001,41.163172,-8.5838214,42461.0046296296,3
656001,41.163237,-8.58381,42461.0046412037,3
656001,41.1632328,-8.5838378,42461.0046527778,3
656001,41.163234,-8.5838637,42461.0046643519,3
656001,41.1632204,-8.583885,42461.0046759259,3
.....
758001,39.9966599,-8.6113725,42461.4125578704,1
758001,39.9969224,-8.6111087,42461.4125694444,1
758001,39.9972031,-8.6108471,42461.4125810185,1
....
829000,40.6022533,-7.2600605,42461.6981944444,2
829000,40.6020222,-7.2601668,42461.6982060185,2
829000,40.6017725,-7.2602641,42461.6982175926,2
829000,40.6015003,-7.2603968,42461.6982291667,2
......
863025,41.1459056,-8.6131507,42461.7629050926,0
863025,41.1459103,-8.6131553,42461.7629166667,0
863025,41.1459149,-8.6131682,42461.7629282407,0
```

Then I want to load this data as array of arrays, by `id` such that each of the nested array has the four columns: `lat, lon, days, mode` in the following form:

```
[
  [41.163172 -8.5838214 42461.0046296296 3]
  [41.163237 -8.58381 42461.0046412037 3]
  [41.1632328 -8.5838378 42461.0046527778 3]
  ...
  [39.9966599 -8.6113725 42461.4125578704 1]
  [39.9969224 -8.6111087 42461.4125694444 1]
  .....
  .....
  [41.1459056 -8.6131507 42461.7629050926 0]
  [41.1459103 -8.6131553 42461.7629166667 0]
  [41.1459149 -8.6131682 42461.7629282407 0]
]
```

I first loaded this data as a `numpy ndarray`, like so:

```
my_data = np.genfromtxt('logs.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=True)
my_data.shape
(22, 5)
```

Then trying to work it further to the desired output (by `id`) however this alters the shape of the intended array:

```
#group by id
unique_id = set(my_data[:,0])
unique_id
{656001.0, 758001.0, 829000.0, 863025.0}

grouped_data = np.array([my_data[my_data[:,0]== pvalue, 1:]
                       for pvalue in unique_id])
grouped_data.shape
(503,)
```

But I want have the shape of the nested array as I would iterate over its elements. I was expecting something of shape `(X,4)`

I then try using `pandas dataframe`, so:

```
data = pd.read_csv('logs.csv')
data.head()
      id       lat         lon        days       mode
0   656001  41.163172   -8.583821   42461.004630    3
1   656001  41.163237   -8.583810   42461.004641    3
2   656001  41.163233   -8.583838   42461.004653    3
3   656001  41.163234   -8.583864   42461.004664    3
4   656001  41.163220   -8.583885   42461.004676    3
```

Apparently, pandas wouldn't yield the intended result:

```
data.groupby('id').head()
      id       lat        lon        days        mode
0   656001  41.163172   -8.583821   42461.004630    3
1   656001  41.163237   -8.583810   42461.004641    3
2   656001  41.163233   -8.583838   42461.004653    3
3   656001  41.163234   -8.583864   42461.004664    3
.....
```

None of my attempts could result in the required array of arrays as shown in the beginning. How do I please do this?

Comment: Just remove the `id` column from the series and you should get what you want.

Comment: How many rows per `id`?  If they are all the same, you can group/reshape into a 3d array.  If they differ, you are out of luck, unless you are prepared to pad the shorter ones.  Expect a list of arrays, or an object array of arrays.

Comment: With your dataframe `data.drop(columns = 'id').to_numpy()`?

Comment: That would produce something similar to `groupby()`

Comment: Why are you grouping by `id`? Your desired result has everything in one big array, not grouped.

Comment: @hpaulj rows per `id` varies, so each of the nested arrays could varying number of elements.

Comment: `[matrix.to_numpy() for _, matrix in df.groupby('id')]`?

Comment: @Alexander Ah, many thanks. Can you please add it as answer?

Comment: Why would you use NumPy arrays for this, instead of a Pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to group on the `id` values and extract each matrix for that `id`.

```
[matrix.to_numpy() for _, matrix in df.groupby('id')]
# or, depending on intended use:
# np.array([matrix.to_numpy() for _, matrix in df.groupby('id')])
```